# Need to know common scenarios to test netsuite application

Tags: netsuite, testcase, scenarios, manual-testing

I need to know what are all testing types and scenarios (manual testing) can do for NetSuite application and how?

I have tested integration with netsuite and sales force 
In that I verified cases such as whether all the mapped data can sync or not, in negative cases I verified such as left mandatory field of netsuite as empty in sales force and try to sync and vice verse, *data type*, *Max length and min length of field limit*, *negative value*